# How to marginBottom view background?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I want to cut a little bit background color to let the text half with it.

[image]

I try to use `marginBottom`, but the text position will move with it.

```
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'pink' }>
    <View style={{ felx: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue', marginBottom: 40, justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 86, color: 'white' }}>Half</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

Is any simple way can achieve it ?

Thanks.

Comment: May be https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-masked-view will help you.

Comment: yes you can do it by giving the style absolute of the Text

Comment: I have tried to use absolute, but it will lose the parent view.

Comment: @KishanBharda
Thanks, but it looks like a little different, it is the text with the color behind the text.

Comment: please explain more we did not get your point

Comment: I get the answer from SDushan, thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is a bit different. Try to insert another View & give `position: 'absolute'` to that view as below,

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'pink' }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue', marginBottom: 40, justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
        <View style={{ bottom: -43, position: 'absolute' }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 86, color: 'white' }}>Half</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

When you assign value to `bottom`make sure to gave half of the font size.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: No doubts with it. It is the solution correctly. Thanks for your help.